# How to prove that the quartic equation $x^4-3x+1=0$ has exactly 2 real roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots, curves, quartics

So I have this quartic equation here:

$x^4-3x+1=0$

I'm supposed to prove this equation has exactly 2 roots.

I defined $f(x)=x^4-3x+1=0$

Then I used the Intermediate value theorem at $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to show it goes from $(0,1)$ to $(1,-1)$ so it must have crossed the x-axis since this polynomial is continuous. So there is at least 1 root.

The derivative is $f'(x)=4x^3-3$ and the second derivative is $f''(x)=12x^2$.

There is a critical point at $x=(3/4)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ where the function changes from increasing from $(-\infty,(3/4)^{\frac{1}{3}}]$ and decreasing from $[(3/4)^{\frac{1}{3}},\infty)$.

There is a point of inflection at $x=0$ where the concavity changes from concave up to concave down.

I'm not really sure how to use this information to determine how to show there is a second root though...

No I can't use Descartes's rule of signs. It would be easy otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it's increasing then decreasing,  so it can have at most two roots (Just by monotonicity).  It can't have exactly 1 real root because complex roots come in pairs, so since you found 1, it must have a second.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot :) . Is this always true with quartics in general?

Comment: you have 0, 2, or 4 real roots....all are possible

Answer (score 6):

The [Sturm Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) for $x^4-3x+1$ is
$$
\left\{x^4-3x+1,\,\,4x^3-3,\,\,\tfrac94x-1,\,\,\tfrac{1931}{729}\right\}
$$
There are $2$ sign changes at $-\infty$: $\{+,-,-,+\}$.

There are $0$ sign changes at $+\infty$: $\{+,+,+,+\}$.

This means there are $2$ real roots.

---

In fact, there are $2$ sign changes at $0$: $\{+,-,-,+\}$.

This means that there are no negative roots and $2$ positive roots.

There is $1$ sign change at $1$: $\{-,+,+,+\}$.

There are $0$ sign changes at $2$: $\{+,+,+,+\}$.

Thus, one of the roots is between $0$ and $1$, and one is between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: I like this a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the result learned in high school algebra.  To find the number of positive real roots, check the number of sign changes in the coefficients of 
$$f(x)=x^4-3x+1.$$
We have positive, then negative, then positive.  2 sign changes, so 2 positive real roots.

To check the number of negative real roots, check the number of sign changes in the coefficients of
$$f(-x)=x^4+3x+1.$$
There are no sign changes, so there are no negative real roots.

Therefore, there are two positive real roots, and two complex roots.

Comment: Descarts rule of signs would give: two sign changes means there are at most 2 positive roots, but there may also be 0 positive roots. N sign changes means there are one of N, N-2, N-4, ... roots

Answer (score 0):

If we "drop" the constant term for the moment, the resulting quartic function $ \ g(x) \ = \ x^4 - 3x $  $ = \ x·(x^3 - 3) \ $ has (single) real zeroes at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ \sqrt[3]{3} \ \ . \ $  Since the curve for this even-degree polynomial "opens upward" (positive leading coefficient), there is a "turning point" (absolute minimum) between these $ \ x-$intercepts for which $ \ f(x_{min}) \ < \ 0 \ \ . \ $  We calculate that $ \ g(1) \ = \ -2 \ \ $ (should we wish more precision, from your first derivative, we obtain $$ \ x_{min} \ = \ \left(\frac34 \right)^{1/3} \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ g(x_{min}) \ \ = \ \ \left(\frac34 \right)^{1/3} · \left(\frac34 - 3 \right) \ \ = \ \  \left(\frac34 \right)^{1/3} · \left(-\frac94 \right) $$ $$ = \ \ \left(-\frac{2187}{256} \right)^{1/3} \ \ < \ \ \left(-\frac{2048}{256} \right)^{1/3} \ \ = \ \ -2 \ \ . \ ) $$

From this, we conclude that the minimum of $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^4 - 3x + 1 \ $ can be *no larger* than $ \ -1 \ \ . \ $  So the curve of this function also has just two $ \ x-$intercepts, hence $ \ f(x) \ $ possesses only two real zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

If the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of a quartic equation with real coefficients is negative then the quartic equation has two real roots and two complex conjugate roots.

The discriminant of the equation $ax^4+dx+e=0$ is $\Delta=256a^3e^3-27a^2d^4$. So, the discriminant of $x^4-3x+1=0$ is $\Delta=256+(-27)(-3)^4=-1931<0$.